# Vaadin 13 Pie Chart is not replacing demo data (web browsers) with my data DataSeriesItem ("Mercury", 4900));

Tags: charts, java-8, vaadin11

I do not want to have the demo data (web browser) in the pie chart. 
I want to overwrite this.
But it does not care. 
It shows no errors but always displays only web browser data. 
Not mine: 
"Mercury", 4900
"Venus", 12100

```
public DowntimeChartView(DowntimeService service) {
    Configuration configurationDowntimeChart = downtimeChart.getConfiguration();
    DataSeries series = new DataSeries();
    series.add(new DataSeriesItem("Mercury", 4900));
    series.add(new DataSeriesItem("Venus", 12100));
    configurationDowntimeChart.setTitle("Verfügbar bzw. Stillstand  19-06-17_16-50");
    configurationDowntimeChart.setSeries(series);
    downtimeChart.drawChart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i deleted the the META-INF/resources/frontend/layouts/view.html:16

```
<vaadin-chart-series title="Brands" values="[[&quot;Chrome&quot;,61.41],[&quot;Internet Explorer&quot;,11.84],[&quot;Firefox&quot;,10.85],[&quot;Edge&quot;,4.67],[&quot;Safari&quot;,4.18],[&quot;Sogou Explorer&quot;,1.64],[&quot;Opera&quot;,1.6],[&quot;QQ&quot;,1.2],[&quot;Other&quot;,2.61]]" content="downtime-chart-view"></vaadin-chart-series> downtime-chart-view
```

Comment: Why do you have a `frontend` folder, if you are using Vaadin 8?